# Promise await blocking loop from finishing

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I need a loop to play 10 sounds in sequence. My first attempt had the sounds overlapping, so I was told that I need to use Promise/await. The code below plays sound 0 then never continues the loop.

(The library I'm using (jscw) is for morse code. You pass it a string, it plays the morse equivalent. Its "onFinished" calls a user-defined function.)

```
async function playAll() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    playMorse(words[i]);
    await playstate();
  }
}

function playstate() {
  playdone = true;
  //console.log(playdone);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.addEventListener('playdone', resolve)
  })
}

function playMorse(z) {
  var m = new jscw();
  playdone = false;
  m.onFinished = function() {
    playstate();
  }
  m.play(z);
}
```

Comment: possibly your 'playstate' never gets resolved, even for the first time

Comment: Do you know whether you are getting the `playdone` message or not?  This seems like it would benefit from some elemental debugging to see what exactly steps are occurring  (put `console.log()` statements in each area of the code) and then when you get a more definitive idea about where it's stuck, we could help you better.

Comment: Your observation makes it seem like `playstate()` never resolves the promise it returns which would happen if the `playdone` event was never received so that is definitely the first item to investigate.  Also, it's doing you no good to call `playstate()` from the `onFinished` handler.  Nothing is using the promise and it's probably too late to do the `addEventListener` at that point anyway.  You may as well just change the state of the variable `playdone` and not call `playstate()` from `onFinished`.

Comment: In addition, you're building up event listeners for `window.addEventListener('playdone', ...)` that you never remove.  While this isn't a disaster in this particular case, it's a troublesome way to code and, in other situations, can lead to bugs or memory leaks.  When you're done with an eventListener on an object that persists, you need to remove that listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems nothing is supposed to fire the `playdone` event you are listening for.
So a simple solution is to fire it in the `onFinished` callback.

```js
const words = ["hello", "world"];
async function playAll() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    console.log("###READING", words[i]);
    playMorse(words[i]);
    await playstate();
  }
}

function playstate() {
  playdone = true;
  //console.log(playdone);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.addEventListener('playdone', resolve, { once: true })
  })
}

function playMorse(z) {
  var m = new jscw();
  playdone = false;
  m.onFinished = function() {
    dispatchEvent( new Event("playdone") );
  }
  m.play(z);
}

btn.onclick = playAll;
```

```html
<script src="https://fkurz.net/ham/jscwlib/src/jscwlib.js"></script>
<button id="btn">play all</button>
```

But you don't need an event here, simply make `playMorse` return a Promise that will resolve in the `onFinished` callback:

```js
const words = ["hello", "world"];
async function playAll() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    console.log("###READING", words[i]);
    await playMorse(words[i]);
  }
}

function playMorse(z) {
  return new Promise( (resolve) => {
    const m = new jscw();
    m.onFinished = resolve;
    m.play(z);
  });
}

btn.onclick = playAll;
```

```html
<script src="https://fkurz.net/ham/jscwlib/src/jscwlib.js"></script>
<button id="btn">play all</button>
```